# CTE and Update needs to be joined

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am fairly new to CTEs but I didnt think what I was trying to do was terribly complicated. Essentially, I want to update a date field with another date field (plus 1 day) and so I thought I would just use a CTE so I could use the temporary table in my update statement.

However, I keep getting the error message `Invalid column name 'effdt_end_new'`. I created the column name in the CTE, when I do a full reference it says that it cannot bind to it. Any ideas?
[image: here is a pic of my query].

The SQL code is

```
   WITH GRAB_END_DATE AS
    (
    SELECT  emplid, LEAD(DATEADD(day,1,effdt),1) OVER(PARTITION BY emplid ORDER BY effdt) AS effdt_end_new
    FROM [dw].[stage_dim_wd_staff_1]
    WHERE emplid = '040089671'
    )

    UPDATE [dw].[stage_dim_wd_staff_1]
    SET effdt_end = effdt_end_new
    WHERE emplid = '040089671'`
```

Comment: you dont need a CTE at all, or is it a requirement ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the CTE, not the base table

```sql
WITH GRAB_END_DATE AS
(
    SELECT
      *,
      LEAD(DATEADD(day, 1, st.effdt)) OVER (PARTITION BY st.emplid ORDER BY st.effdt) AS effdt_end_new
    FROM dw.stage_dim_wd_staff_1 st
    WHERE emplid = '040089671'
)
UPDATE GRAB_END_DATE
SET effdt_end = effdt_end_new;
```

Note that there is no join here, the CTE is updated directly, and this feeds through to the base table of the CTE.

You can also do this using a derived table or a view, it's the same thing.

```sql
UPDATE GRAB_END_DATE
SET effdt_end = effdt_end_new
FROM (
    SELECT
      *,
      LEAD(DATEADD(day, 1, st.effdt)) OVER (PARTITION BY st.emplid ORDER BY st.effdt) AS effdt_end_new
    FROM dw.stage_dim_wd_staff_1 st
    WHERE emplid = '040089671'
) GRAB_END_DATE;
```

Comment: isnt he overcomplicating things with CTEs ?

Comment: @jmvcollaborator No, you have to use `LEAD` inside a CTE or derived table, you cannot use it at the top-level scope.